# After using destructors, the code shows "reference to Book::~Book()" error

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learner in C++ and I am into the topic of constructors and destructors. I have compiled the code below and it returns the undefined reference to Book::~Book() error. But when I comment out the destructor, it is working fine. I think I can create member functions after using destructors. What am I doing wrong here? I have written my code below for better undertsanding

```
class Book
{
private:
    int *pages;
    int *price;

public:
    Book()        //default constructor
    {
        pages = new int;
        price = new int;
        *pages = 300;
        *price = 8;
    };  

    void pre_destructor()
    {
        std::cout << "The pages:" << *pages;
        std::cout << "The price:" << *price;
    }

~Book();             //destructor

    void post_destructor()
    {
        std::cout << "The pages:" << *pages << "\n";
        std::cout << "The price:" << *price << "\n";
        delete pages;
        delete price;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    Book book1;

    cout << "Before using destructors" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------"<< endl;

    book1.pre_destructor();

    cout << "After using destructors" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------";

    book1.post_destructor();

    return 0;
}  //destructor is called here
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You forgot to implement the destructor; `~Book();`is just its declaration.

Comment: I made the edit. But now it shows "expected ; at end of member declaration" pointing at the line where the destructor is called

Comment: Having specific clean-up functions is usually bad design if you have to manually call them, because you can forget to call them or an exception can occur. Consider placing them inside your destructor instead.

Comment: @Kiran I find it fortunate that you want to start with C++11 right away, as I can take from the tags. Make sure to make it a habit to avoid unattended pointers whenever possible and use [std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead. That would e.g. here have avoided the necessity to implement a custom dtor (short for "destructor").

Comment: You appear to think that the order in which you add members to your class somehow controls the order the code is run?  It doesn't.  The lines in `main()` that call member functions determines the order the code runs.

Answer (score 2):

I've shortened that a little. the former `void pre_destructor()` was pointless; that's better placed in the dtor (short for "destructor") itself, 
and the `post_destructor()` was even potentially harmful.

```
#include <iostream>

class Book
{
private:
    int *pages;
    int *price;

public:
    Book() : pages(new int(300)), price(new int(8)) {}  

    ~Book() {
        std::cout << "The pages:" << *pages << "\n";
        std::cout << "The price:" << *price << "\n";
        delete price;
        delete pages;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    {
        Book book1;
    } //destructor is called here

    return 0;
}
```

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76f78140a8d29675) at Coliru's**

Answer (score 1):

Your destructor is declared, but never defined.

Looks like "post_destructor" does the actual destruction.  As a result, all you need to do is write you destructor as follows:

```
~Book() {}  // empty, nothing to do here...
```

Comment: There is definitely something to do in the destructor. Look at his data members. He also has two functions called `pre_destructor()` and `post_destructor()`. He has to free the memory allocated in his constructor.

Comment: Yea, but he's already "destructing" in post_destructor().  I agree there are pointer here, but if he calls "post_destructor()" manually it's already deleted before the actual destructor gets called.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure why he has pre and post destructor and doesn't just do the destruction inside the destructor...

Comment: You're right. I didn't look at the code in `main()`.